# How do we pass the field api name in lwc for a lightning data table?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have fetched all the fields to be displayed on the datatable in my apex query.

In my js file where i store the column details

```
@track columns = [{
        label: 'Deal Name',
        fieldName: 'Marketing_Activity__r.Name',
        type: 'text'            
    },
    {
        label: 'Deal Type',
        fieldName: 'Deal_Type__c',
        type: 'text'

    },
    {
        label: 'Rent',
        fieldName : 'Rent__c',
        type: 'currency'

    },
    {
        label: 'Term',
        fieldName : 'Term_Mos__c',
        type: 'number'
    },
    {
        label: 'Security Deposit',
        fieldName: 'Aircraft__r.Lease__r.Security_Deposit_Amount_Cash_or_LOC__c',
        type: 'currency'

    }
```

It fetches value for rent,term and deal_type. but not for Security deposit and Deal Name.
Any suggestions???
How to display the above details on the datatable in lwc?

Answer (score 1):

You can't traverse relationships in the fieldName attribute. Instead, you would need to map the data beforehand, then use that field's name.

```
@track error;
@track data;

@wire(methodName, { /* params here */ })
  wireDealInfo({ error, data }) {
    if(data) {
      this.data = data
        .map(row => { ...row, dealName: row.Marketing_Activity__r.Name })
        .map(row => { ...row, securityDeposit: row.Aircraft__r.Lease__r.Security_Deposit_Amount_Cash_or_LOC__c });
      this.error = null;
    }
    if(error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.data = [];
    }
  }
```

Then, for your data table columns:

```
@track columns = [{
    label: 'Deal Name',
    fieldName: 'dealName',
    type: 'text'            
},
// ... other rows the same
{
    label: 'Security Deposit',
    fieldName: 'securityDeposit',
    type: 'currency'
}];
```